# Matrix which gives the existence in a graph of a path of length $k$

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

In a graph $G$, for some $k$, I am looking to get a 0-1 matrix whose $ij^{\text{th}}$ entry is 1 whenever vertex $i$ has a path of length $k$ to vertex $j$ in $G$, and is otherwise zero.

I have been doing this with `FindPath[graph,i,j,{k}]`, and entering all vertex pairs $ij$, then using `Length` to obtain a zero or one. But this takes a long time in large graphs, particularly when $k$ is large.

Considering a 1d random geometric graph, define the functions for building the graph:

```
edges6 = Function[{subsets, b}, 
   Pick[subsets, 
    UnitStep[
     RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length@subsets] - 
      Exp[-b (subsets[[All, 1]] - subsets[[All, 2]])^2]], 0]];
gr6[vert_, r0_] := 
  Graph[vert, UndirectedEdge @@@ edges6[Subsets[vert, {2}], 1/r0^2]];
makegraph2[nv_, coord_, width_, height_, r0_] := 
  Module[{pts, newvertices, newedges, edges, alledges, allpts, e1, e2,
     ew}, allpts = 
    Table[RandomReal[{-width/2, width/2}], {i, 1, nv}];
   allpts = Join[allpts, coord];
   (****Add edge weights****)
   pdg1 = gr6[allpts, r0]
   ];
```

and then run

```
gr = makegraph2[100, {0}, 10, 0.01, 0.5];
Length[FindPath[gr, #, Last@VertexList[gr], {6}]] & /@ VertexList[gr] // AbsoluteTiming
```

which gives

{0.657717, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

which is a list of 0's and 1's which determines the existence of a six-hop path from each node, to the node at $0$. I can try and speed it up with IGDistanceCounts, but this only gives shortest paths. Is there way to do it quicker than with `FindPath`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not work with [`AdjacencyMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyMatrix) instead? For example:

```
KPaths[g_, k_] := Module[{a, m},
    a = AdjacencyMatrix[g];
    m = 1 - IdentityMatrix[Length[a]];
    Nest[Unitize[(a . #) m]&, a, k-1]
]
```

Comparison:

```
SeedRandom[1];
gr=makegraph2[100,{0},10,0.01,0.5];
last = Length[FindPath[gr,#,Last@VertexList[gr],{6}]]&/@VertexList[gr]; //AbsoluteTiming
last
```

> {0.104942, Null}

> {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
> 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
> 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
> 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}

```
r = KPaths[gr, 6]; //AbsoluteTiming
r[[-1]] //Normal

last == r[[-1]]
```

> {0.002574, Null}

> {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
> 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
> 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
> 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}

> True

Note that `KPaths` does all of the vertices instead of just the last vertex.

Comment: Ok very nice, thank you. How do you get round the idea that the powers of the adjacency matrix gives the walks of length k, rather than the paths? I always thought the powers can only count walks, which repeat edges and vertices. So it is possible for these two lists to differ, if have a walk of length 6, but no path of length 6, e.g. by traversing a path of length 4, then moving forward and pack along one edge.

Comment: @apkg That's why I multiply by the matrix `m`, which is `1 - IdentityMatrix[Length[a]]`. This basically zeros out the diagonal after every "power".

Comment: So that cancels out the walks? Leaving only the paths?

Comment: @apkg Yes, I think so.

Comment: Why does the diagonal matter? I assume it is to stop the path, at any stage, running between itself and itself? Then this has the effect on the powers of A of not counting paths which repeat a vertex.

Answer (score 2):

A method using `` SparseArray`SparseArrayRemoveDiagonal `` to remove the diagonal:

```
ClearAll[urd, kPaths1, kPaths2]

urd = Unitize @* SparseArray`SparseArrayRemoveDiagonal;

kPaths1[g_, k_] := Module[{a = AdjacencyMatrix @ g}, Nest[urd[a.#] &, a, k - 1]]
```

***Example:***

```
SeedRandom[1];

gr = makegraph2[100, {0}, 10, 0.01, 0.5];

r1 = kPaths1[gr, 6]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.00078
> ```

In comparison, Carl's `KPaths` we get

```
r = KPaths[gr, 6]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.0017
> ```

All three methods give the same result:

```
r == r1
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: They don't always give the same result, try `SeedRandom[7]`. I think the diagonal needs to be removed after each dot product.

Comment: Thank you @Carl. Looks like  moving `urd` inside `Nest` and `MatrixPower` fixes the issue and does not have significant effect on timings.

Comment: `kPaths2` still gives an answer different from both `kPaths1` and `KPaths` when using  `SeedRandom[7]`.

Comment: Thank you again @Carl. Deleted `kPaths2`.